# How to slide views in Android

Tags: android, layout

I have two image views in a table layout (two cells). Only one of the image views has an image displayed (the other is blank).

When a user taps on the view with the image, I would like the image to transition into the empty view.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html). If I were doing it, I would set the first one(which starts with the pic in it) to View.GONE, set the other to VISIBLE, then apply a translate animation to the second one that will slide it from the position of the first to where it is supposed to be.

[This page has a nice tutorial on how to use various types of animations.](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)